# What property MSBuild -target switch sets in project

Tags: msbuild

When running msbuild task as in

```
msbuild -t Pack
```

Can I check a property

```
$(xxx.Contains('Pack'))
```

to see what was passed? In the documentation I only found InitialTargets and DefaultTargets and neither seems to work.

I tried checking

```
$(InitialTargets.Contains('Pack'))
$(DefaultTargets.Contains('Pack'))
$(Targets.Contains('Pack'))
```

but the condition never passed.

Comment: The value of the `-target` switch is not available as a property or item. `InitialTargets` and `DefaultTargets` are attributes of the [`Project` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/project-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022), are not available as properties or items, and are not changed by the `-targets` switch. MSBuild is declarative, not procedural. If you need to perform something before a `Pack`, create a target with `BeforeTargets="_GetPackageFiles"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run a target before pack, in the end I solved it by overriding PackDependsOn property. This however does not work out of the box for sdk projects. You have to import it manually.

```
<Project>
 <Import Project"Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

 <PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

 <PropertyGroup>
  <PackDependsOn>
   CustomBeforePack;
   $(PackDependsOn)
  </PackDependsOn>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <Target Name="CustomBeforePack">
  <Message Text="Custom before pack" Importance="high"/>
  <!-- Include all files from the project output into the content folder in the nuget package -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(OutputPath)\**\*.*" Pack="true" PackagePath="content" />
  </ItemGroup>
 </Target>

</Project>
```